# Migrate postgresql data directory from Windows to Mac[Silicon Based]

Tags: postgresql, migration

I have 4TB external portable hard disk with exFat formatting. Every day I use this disk as data directory for my postgresql 16. Every day I plug that external hard drive in my office windows pc and work. After office work done I carry that drive to my home. I have silicon based mac in my home. Now my question is how can I use that data directory in my home macbook pro?

Comment: If that data is precious to you, then you shouldn't do this. Plugging it into another OS may damage data. Additionally there is a higher possibility of physical damage while it is being carried. Instead, set up a replication system to your home.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. You can only do that if both machines run the same operating system and have the same architecture, and you need to make sure that the C library version (or the version of the ICU library, if you are using ICU collations) are the same on both systems.